# How to properly cast NSSingleEntryDictionaryI

Tags: swift

I have this method for posting and getting response

```
    //Add to Cart Method
    func cart(){

        //getting userId from defaults
        let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard
        let userId = defaultValues.string(forKey: "userid")

        //creating parameters for the post request
        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "userId":Int(userId!)!
        ]

        //Defined a constant that holds the URL for our web service
        let URL_SELECT_FROM_CART = "http://localhost:8888/restaurant/cart.php?"

        Alamofire.request(URL_SELECT_FROM_CART, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
            response in
            //printing response
            print(response)

            let result = response.result.value

            //converting it as NSDictionary
           let jsonData = result as! [[String:Any]]


        }
    }
```

here is my response output

```
SUCCESS: {
    cartItem =     (
                {
            addedTime = "2018-06-20 22:22:52";
            additionalNote = "";
            cartId = 20;
            recipeName = Friedrice;
            recipePrice = "GHS 20";
            recipeQuantity = 2;
            restaurantName = Chucks;
            status = 1;
            totalCost = "2 Plates cost GHS 40";
            userId = 9;
        }
    );
}
```

When I run the project, I get

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x10472be98) to 'NSArray' (0x10472cf28).
```

I know its coming from the way I am casting my objects but how to handle it is my problem, I am relative new to swift.
Thanks for your review and help.

Comment: `let result = response.result.value`                                    
`let jsonData = result as! [[String:Any]]` , here is whats giving me the error @Malleswari

Comment: `__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI` => It means, it's a `Dictionary` with only one Key. `[[String:Any]]`, that's an `Array` of `Dictionaries` (dictionaries that can have one or more keys, it doesn't matter). So `[[String:Any]]` => `[String: Any]`.

Comment: thanks @Larme.. now how do I extract the string values

Comment: That’s another question. And a basic one: how do you get values from a dictionary? Look for it